# Does Anorm support bulk insert?

Tags: scala, anorm

I want to copy data from SQL server to vertica in Scala, and I am thinking of using Anorm, but I didn't find any doc about bulk insert. If Anorm doesn't support bulk insert, what library I should use?

Comment: There is `BatchSql`, but it's slow. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573242/batch-insert-with-table-that-has-many-columns-using-anorm/24575568#24575568

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does, using `BatchSql`. Here's an example straight from the tests

```
BatchSql(
  "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE a = {a}, b = {b}",
  Seq(
    Seq[NamedParameter]("a" -> 0, "b" -> -1),
    Seq[NamedParameter]("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
  )
)
```

However, as @LimbSoup noted in the comments, this doesn't execute faster than executing multiple inserts in sequence, as it uses `executeBatch` under the hood to send a statement containing a sequence of queries to the database.

The only performance gain will come from the network latency (since a single statement is sent to the database).

See this answer for an alternative approach: [Batch insert with table that has many columns using Anorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573242/batch-insert-with-table-that-has-many-columns-using-anorm/24575568#24575568)

Comment: Keep in mind this will run the inserts one at a time and not in a single statement, which can be very slow if there is a lot of data to move.

Comment: I looked through the implementation of `BatchSql` and I can't verify what you say. It looks like anorm properly performs a batch query, can you point me to the relevant code that proves your assumption?

Comment: Let me correct my meaning. It will send the queries to the database in a batch, however it won't magically change 100 inserts into a single insert. If the OP is looking to move a lot of data, there is a huge performance difference.

Comment: @LimbSoup ok I get what you mean. I added a note to my answer.

Comment: Using latest version 2.5.1 gives: "Symbol BatchSql is deprecated, Use BatchSql(sql, first, other) instead"