# Play-Scala: call another function inside DB.withConnection

Tags: scala, playframework

I want to call a function inside a function with `DB.connection`, If I simply use the code below, I got this error: `could not find implicit value for parameter connection: java.sql.Connection`.

```
def insert(data: Recap, action_type: String, username: String, parent_page: String) =  DB.withConnection { implicit c => 
        //other code is omitted
            case Some(last_inserted_id) => {
                if(parent_page == "SO")
                    insert_SO(data, employee_id, status, last_inserted_id)//problem
                else if(parent_page == "PO")
                    insert_PO(data, employee_id, status, last_inserted_id)//problem
        //other code is omitted
    }

def insert_SO(data: Recap, employee_id: String, status: Int, last_inserted_id: Long) = {
        var so_id_list: Set[Long] = Set()
        for(ls <- data.recap_items)
            for(rs <- ls.invoice_items)
                so_id_list = so_id_list ++ Set(rs.id)

        for(ls <- so_id_list){
            if(status == 20){
                SQL("""UPDATE salesorder SET recap_id = {recap_id}, approved_id = {approved_id}, approved_datetime = NOW(), status = 20 WHERE salesorder.id = {so_id}""").on(
                'recap_id -> last_inserted_id, 'approved_id -> employee_id, 'so_id -> ls).executeUpdate()
       //other code is omitted
    }
def insert_PO(data: Recap, employee_id: String, status: Int, last_inserted_id: Long) = {
        var po_id_list: Set[Long] = Set()
        for(ls <- data.recap_items)
            for(rs <- ls.invoice_items)
                po_id_list = po_id_list ++ Set(rs.id)

        for(ls <- po_id_list){
            if(status == 20){
                SQL("""UPDATE PurchaseOrder SET recap_id = {recap_id}, approved_id = {approved_id}, approved_datetime = NOW(), status = 20 WHERE PurchaseOrder.id = {po_id}""").on(
                'recap_id -> last_inserted_id, 'approved_id -> employee_id, 'po_id -> ls).executeUpdate()
        //other code is omitted
    }
```

I believe it will work if I add `DB.withConnection` into the `insert_SO` and `insert_PO` function, however I'm not sure if that's a good practice since I create another connection with DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `Connection` to run a query, and you can retrieve one from the `play.api.db.DB` helper

```
  def insert_SO(data: Recap, employee_id: String, status: Int, last_inserted_id: Long) = {
    DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
        // other operations
        SQL(......).executeUpdate()
    }
  }
```

`withConnection` acquire and closes the connection every time it is called.

try to neglect a for loop
use `Batch Query` in place of `for loop`

```
def insert_SO(data: Recap, employee_id: String, status: Int, last_inserted_id: Long) = {    
 DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  //other operations
  val posQuery = SQL("""UPDATE salesorder SET recap_id = {recap_id}, approved_id = {approved_id}, approved_datetime = NOW(), status = 20 WHERE salesorder.id = {so_id}""")
  val posBatchQuery = (posQuery.asBatch /: so_id_list){(sql, ls) =>
    sql.addBatchParams(last_inserted_id,employee_id,ls)
  }  
  val posBatchAry = posBatchQuery.execute
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I know that solution, however I look for another solution if any.. Because if I add withConnection, it will produce nested connection which I think not a good practice..

Comment: @user26409021 its a bad way to use for loop , try to use a `batch query`

Comment: Can you show an example of how to use batch query ? Because I'm still a newbie in play.. Maybe you can use sql update above as an example.

Comment: Thanks.. Just one to share this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573242/batch-insert-with-table-that-has-many-columns-using-anorm , which say that `BatchQuery` only reduce network latency..